# Why am I getting [object Object] after accessing JSON data?

Tags: javascript, api, get

I am making a simple GET request and filling up a webpage with some data. Every other line works except for 'addresses' which contains two arrays, and on my webpage it prints out '[object Object]', instead of the data. Here is an example of the JSON (apologies for the poor formatting):

```
data: Array(7)
   0:
   addresses: Array(2)
   0:
     city: "Houghton"
     line1: "800 East Lakeshore Drive"
     line2: ""
     line3: ""
     postalCode: "49931"
     stateCode: "MI"
     type: "Physical"
```

**proto**: Object

Here is the code block where I try to access 'addresses':

```
for (let i = 0; i < parkData.length; i++) {
    $("#results-list").append(`<h2>${parkData[i].fullName}</h2>
    <p>${parkData[i].addresses[0]}</p>
    <a href=${parkData[i].directionsUrl}>Directions</a><br>
    <a href=${parkData[i].url}>Website</a>
    <p>${parkData[i].description}</p>
```

Like I said above, all of the other lines work but when I try to get the first index of addresses I just get that weird Object response. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: This is not JSON. This is javascript object data. They are different

Comment: Show us the complete `parkData` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` means that it's not a string but an object that (probably) has an address as property of this object, i.e. instead of `parkData[i].addresses[0]` you need to access some property (which one I cannot tell from your code as you are not showing the whole object that you got from JSON), for example like this:

```js
const {city, line1} = parkData[i].addresses[0].city
const fullAddress = `City: {city}, Address: {line1}`
```

And only then, after constructing the address, you add it into your page as `fullAddress`

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to go deeper in some of the properties for sure. Double check every iteration and you will find that you are appending an object. I think you didn’t paste all the response. You can use jsonviewer to better see the structure

Edit-> As I can see...address is an object, so you need to iterate over it in order to append strings.

So it would be: ... address[0].map(a => ... a.someAddressProperty

Comment: Hi, I just edited the original post and added the full Object. The address is broken up into different lines so I am unsure of how to get the full address.